# 'Alajax' Jquery simple form submit. How to prevent submitting if form not validated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I was looking for a simple JQuery plugin to make it easy to submit forms via Ajax and I found [Alajax](http://www.alajax.com/) which I found handy as it integrates into a typical HTML form and does all the job. Unfortunately I don't understand how to prevent the form to be sumbitted if it is not validated (the official web site is quite poor of documentation, nor the author has answered my mail).

For example the following form is submitted via Ajax: the plugin intecepts the form, grabs the 'name' attributes and call *send.php* as a normal form

```
<form id="myform" action="send.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstname"
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#myform").alajax();
    });
</script>
```

Alajax has some [options](https://github.com/alaabadran/ALAJAX) as explained:

```
$('#myform').alajax({
    type: '' // Type of return value. Default is "text". Other values are: "json", "xml", "jsonp"
    beforeSend: function (){} // Code to run before sending the form
    success: function(){} // Code to run when the AJAX call success
    error: function(){} // Code to run when error occures
});
```

But the following code still submits the form:

```
$('#myform').alajax({
    beforeSend: function (){
        // Validation code is here. Suppose that form is not validated,
        return false; // this should'nt stop submitting the form?
    }
});
```

The code inside the *beforeSend* option is correctly executed (as I tested it with a call to console.log), but the form is still submitted. How I can prevent the form to be submitted upon an error? I also tried **preventDefault** without success.

Comment: the library swallows your return value from the beforeSend function. see how it gets called: https://github.com/alaabadran/ALAJAX/blob/master/js/alajax.js#L41

Comment: I see but I don't understand.

Comment: from its name `beforeSend` its quite reasonable to think that the request will be send after that function executes no matter what is in that function, so you cannot check if a form is valid there. Do it before dispatching AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent the form submition with alajax. however you can use another submit listener to prevent the event from reaching alajax.

```
<form id="myform" action="send.php">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){

    $("#myform").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(/* form is invalid */){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    });

    $("#myform").alajax();
  });
</script>
```

**edit**

There is another way you can `throw new Error('asd');` inside the beforeSend function.